# Redirecting Html click to specific area of other page

Tags: php, html, css

i am doing  two simple news pages , Scenario is as i have posted news `head line  and its description on page news.html` and there is a read more button , `when user will click read more button it will take to  a page news_detail.html` , now what i want  if user clicks on first news from news.html page should bring up first news from detal.htmml and if user clicks on second news it should focus on second news while details for all  the news is  on same page ,

i know how to direct to specific link with in same page but if we have to on another page and have to focus on specific news how it will happen ? please help me with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give each news a unique id, like so:

```
<div id="news1">
<!-- news content -->
</div>

<div id="news2">
<!-- news content -->
</div>

<div id="news3">
<!-- news content -->
</div>

...
```

Now, you can simply redirect the users after appending the news ID to the URL as below:

```
news.html#news1
news.html#news2
news.html#news3
```